# Game Physics With RK4 Implementation For A 2D Platformer

Tags: c++, implementation, game-physics

I been reading about RK4 for physics implementation in a game, so I read in some pages and all people recommend me this page:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

This page shows clearly how this one works, but I can't figure out how to implement in my game, maybe I don't understand that good but I find some things that are not really clearly to me.

In my game, the player decides when change direction in the X-Axis but I can't figure out how with this RK4 implementation change the direction of the object, in the example the point goes side to side but I don't understand how I can control when he goes right or left.

So if anyone can give a little bit of clarity in this implementation and my problem which I do not understand I will be really grateful.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: "the player decides when change direction in the X-axis"... when what changes direction? The player, an object? Your RK4 integrator has very little to do with this. If you're trying to affect an object you can apply forces or impulses. You don't change or modify the integrator. Please explain clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a little late and I didn't check the post right. The player decides when changes direction of his character when he presses the right key or left key, so you say that to solve this problem I must apply a force that change the direction of the player?